# z-index issue of absolute element inside absolute div

Tags: html, css

I need an idea about a z-index issue on IE. Here’s my html markup:

```
   <div style="position:relative">
        <div style="position:absolute">
           <a style="position:absolute"> close button </a>
        </div>
   </div>
```

The anchor (close button) is partially outside of it’s parent (top: -4px; right: -4px;) but it gets cut at the parent’s border. Is there a way to make the anchor look right?

Later edit: http://jsfiddle.net/RTTkU/1/

Comment: I put together a jfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/kBe8S/2/ .  Could you provide a little more info about the problem, maybe a little more code?  Not really sure what effect you are going for.

Comment: I take it that you tried z-index already and it didn't work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kBe8S/10/ a jsfiddle to make it a bit more clear http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/73895356.jpg/ http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/233/26231636.jpg/ The cut one is from IE 7&8.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to make the z-indexes work. Any suggestions Dave?

Comment: Have you remembered to set a doctype for the page? Have you ensured that the a-tag has layout?

Comment: I've added a new jsfiddle in the question. It seems like the problem is the filter -ms-filter property I'm applying to IE for drop shadow. Bad choice. I'll move the button outside the search box and that's all. If you have any other solution please let me know. Thanks everyone for pointing me to the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IE specific "filter" property applied to a box acts as "overflow: hidden;" thus cropping every child element which crosses the boundaries of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Post whatever you have so far so we can take a look, but in the mean time i made a small demo that you can try out to see if its what you're looking for:

**CSS**

```
.box {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

.close {
    position:absolute;
    top:-6px;
    right:-6px;
}

.close a {
    background: url(http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png) no-repeat transparent;
    display:inline-block;
    height:22px;
    width:22px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">
       <a title="Close" href="#">close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/YbbaQ/)

Answer (score -2):

You probably need `overflow: visible` on the parent(s).

Comment: not working. the result is the same. please check my previous comment. thanks!